# How to make a thrown object rotate automatically based on the direction its thrown in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

so what I am trying to do is pull a spear back(like a slingshot) and send it flying, all the while making it rotate while it's flying in the air to mimic a real thrown spear. So far, I have only been able to make it rotate after a few seconds to a certain position but I can already tell that this isn't really a permanent fix and will definitely lead to problems down the line. I have tried looking for better ways of rotating the object but I can't really find anybody else who had a problem like this and it's hard to understand the unity documentation regarding rotation as it's for 3D objects.

Here is a gif showing how it looks like:
https://gfycat.com/chiefglasshorsemouse

This is the code that I have attached to my spear object that's responsible for letting me pull it back and launch it with the mouse:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class spear : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    Vector3 velocity;

    private Vector3 _initialPosition;

    [SerializeField] private float _launchPower = 500;

    bool rotating = false;

    public GameObject objectToRotate;

    private float _timeSittingAround;

    private bool _spearWasLaunched;
    [SerializeField] private float _spearRotation = 360;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  
    }

   
    //rotates the spear
    IEnumerator rotateObject(GameObject gameObjectToMove, Quaternion newRot, float duration)
    {
        if(rotating)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        rotating = true;

        Quaternion currentRot = gameObjectToMove.transform.rotation;

        float counter = 0;
        while(counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            gameObjectToMove.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRot, newRot, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }

        
        
            rotating = false;
        
    }

    //reloads the scene if spear goes out of bounds or lays dormant for 2 seconds
    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, _initialPosition);
        


        if (_spearWasLaunched && 
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude <= 0.1)
        {
            _timeSittingAround += Time.deltaTime;
        }
       
        if(transform.position.y > 30 || 
            transform.position.y < -12.5 ||
            transform.position.x > 40 ||
            transform.position.x < -20 ||
            _timeSittingAround > 2)
        {
            string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
        }

    }

    //slingshot mechanic
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
    }

    
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;

    }



    //launches the spear when mouse is released as well as begins the rotating mechanic 
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * _launchPower);

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;

        _spearWasLaunched = true;

        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = false;



        Quaternion rotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, _spearRotation));
        StartCoroutine(rotateObject(objectToRotate, rotation2, 3f));

        
    }


    



}
```

Comment: Spears and arrows should face the direction of travel, due to air resistance and having a tip that is heavier than the shaft...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Do you know of a way I can add weight to just the tip to make it rotate naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. You could try setting up rigidbodies and maybe joints and weighting different parts so that the tip of the spear naturally rotates the spear. More info on that here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/14899/realistic-rotation-of-flying-arrow.html

There's also another solution in that link for doing it with one line of code, making it rotate in the direction of movement.

In the top of your class, add this:

```
public Rigidbody2D mySpear;
```

Then in the inspector, drag the spear object into that slot to assign it. Then in your code, remove all your rotation code. In Update() add this:

```
 mySpear.transform.right =
Vector2.Slerp(mySpear.transform.right, mySpear.rigidbody.velocity.normalized, Time.deltaTime)
```

A third way to do it is...

1. Figure out the rotation (on the z axis) of the object when it's pointing directly down. Put that down as a constant called downRotation or something.
2. Set a minimum velocity and maximum velocity that will be used by the rotation.
3. I recommend also adding an AnimationCurve variable.
4. Instead of having a special function for rotation, just put it in FixedUpdate. If the spear's velocity.x is not 0, then rotate.
5. The speed of the rotation should be based on the speed of the object. If the object's x velocity is very slow then it would probably fall (rotate) more quickly. If it's going very fast, the rotation would not change much.

Don't use this exact code, but it'd look something like this:

```
// This part figures out how fast rotation should be based on how fast the object is moving
var curve = speedCurve.Evaluate(1 - ((rigidBody.velocity.x - minVelocity) / (maxVelocity - minVelocity)));

// Rotates the spear
var rotate = rigidBody.rotation.eulerAngles;
var speed = curve * rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
rotate.z = Mathf.MoveTowards(rotate.z, downRotation, speed); 
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotate);
```

Side note: You should use rigidbody rotation like I am here, and you should be assigning components to variables in the inspector instead of calling GetComponent every frame.

Comment: I tried the first code sample you posted but nothing is happening. is the myArrow from the code the gameobject name? and in which method am I supposed to put it in

Comment: I realized that code was inaccurate because it was from 2010. Also you're doing things in 2D. So I've updated that section with better information.

Comment: Holy shit it works! It was pointing upwards with mySpear.transform.right so I played around and used .up and it worked! Thanks for the help man.